# Join three tables with group by to get counts

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have three tables- Ad(Id,AgentId,AdDesc,AdTitle,EmailId,ADate), AdComment(ComId,email,comment,AdId) and MyLikes(LikeId,email,AdId). Here I have to join three tables and display Ad table's all fields along with number of comments from AdComment table based on every Ad Id(Ad.Id=AdComment.AdId) and number of likes from MyLikes based on a given email for every Ad Id(Ad.Id=MyLikes.AdId).

When I just joined Ad and Ad comment I used -

```
SELECT * , (
SELECT COUNT( c.AdId )
) AS ComCount
FROM Ad a
LEFT JOIN AdComment c ON a.Id = c.AdId 
GROUP BY a.Id
ORDER BY a.Id DESC
```

This is working fine.

Also when I joined Ad and MyLikes I used -

```
SELECT a.Id, (
SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM MyLikes m
WHERE (
m.email = 'nik@gmail.com'
AND m.AdId = a.Id
)
) AS MyCount
FROM Ad a
LEFT JOIN MyLikes m ON a.Id = m.AdId
GROUP BY a.Id
```

This is working fine.

But when I tried all three table join it is not working, gives some wrong value for comment count. 
For this I used-

```
SELECT a.Id,a.AgentId,a.EmailId,a.AdTitle,a.AdDesc, (
SELECT COUNT(m.AdId)
FROM MyLikes m
WHERE (
m.email = 'nik@gmail.com'
AND m.AdId = a.Id
)
) AS MyCount,(
SELECT COUNT( c.AdId )
) AS ComCount
FROM Ad a
LEFT JOIN MyLikes m ON a.Id = m.AdId LEFT JOIN AdComment c ON a.Id = c.AdId
GROUP BY a.Id ORDER BY a.Id DESC
```

How can I join these three tables and get the desired result.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using subqueries to `count` your data in the `joins` instead:

```
select a.Id, a.AgentId, a.EmailId, a.AdTitle, a.AdDesc, 
       b.AdIdCount, c.AdIdCount
from Ad a
       left join (select AdId, count(*) AdIdCount 
                  from AdComment 
                  group by AdId) b ON a.Id = b.AdId 
       left join (select AdId, count(*) AdIdCount 
                  from MyLikes 
                  where email = 'nik@gmail.com'
                  group by AdId) c ON a.Id = c.AdId
```

---

If you prefer `correlated subqueries`, then this should work:

```
select a.Id, a.AgentId, a.EmailId, a.AdTitle, a.AdDesc, 
       (select count(*) 
        from AdComment b 
        where a.Id = b.AdId),
       (select count(*) 
        from MyLikes c 
        where c.email = 'nik@gmail.com' and 
            a.Id = c.AdId)
from Ad a
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that LikeID and ComId are the unique id fields of the MyLikes and AdComment tables then you should be able to just use a pair of joins and count the distinct id fields from each table:-

```
SELECT a.Id,
        a.AgentId,
        a.EmailId,
        a.AdTitle,
        a.AdDesc,
        COUNT(DISTINCT m.LikeId) AS MyCount,
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.ComId) AS ComCount
FROM Ad a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyLikes m ON m.email = 'nik@gmail.com' AND a.Id = m.AdId
LEFT JOIN AdComment c ON a.Id = c.AdId
```